# Update values of jquery range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I'm using Jquery range slider for search for prices. I have left side where is search panel and the right side where I show the vehicles. The vehicles I get from the API with an ajax call. In `success` function of ajax call I have code as follows:

```
success: function (result) {    
     vehicles_spinner.addClass("hidden");

     $('#' + target_id).fadeOut(80, function () {
          $(this).html(result).fadeIn(80); 
          $.HSCore.components.HSCarousel.init('[class*="js-carousel"]');
    });

    loadFilters();
},
```

Thus I'm using fadeOut and the fadeIn to show nice effect when the list of vehicles shows up. That works fine.

The problem is in jquery's range slider. To be able to update the values of the slider it needs to be initializated as follows:

```
let price_slider = $("#vehicles #price-slider");
$.HSCore.components.HSSlider.init(price_slider);
```

Thus I update the values as follows:

```
price_slider.slider('values', 0, min_price);
price_slider.slider('values', 1, max_price);
```

But they are not updated until I init the slider again. Thus the code that I use to update it is as follows:

```
let price_slider = $("#vehicles #price-slider");
price_slider.slider('values', 0, min_price);
price_slider.slider('values', 1, max_price);
$.HSCore.components.HSSlider.init(price_slider);
```

It works fine but the problem is that it goes a few times in ajax success function and the list of vehicles fade out and fade in a few times and it doesn't look so nice.

I have feeling that the updating values of the slider refreshes the page.

When I update the values without `$.HSCore.components.HSSlider.init(price_slider);` i get something as follows:

[image]

The list of vehicles fade out and fade in one time, what is what I want, thus that is fine, but the slider doesn't look good.

When I do not use `$.HSCore.components.HSSlider.init(price_slider);` the slider looks fine:

[image]

But the list of vehicles fade out and fade in a few times.

Any idea how to solve it? I hoop that I could explain it.

Comment: Delegation is your friend. You can't really do much directly with elements that were added after the DOM loaded. So you have to access them through a parent node that was already there when the DOM was loaded.
Here's an example I built a while back: https://jsfiddle.net/difster/cbtrzozt/

Comment: @Difster That is why I use `#vehicles`. Div with that id is always there.